# How do i control visibility Form1 from Form2

Tags: c#, c, vb.net, c#-4.0, controls

I want to make Form1.Visable=true and Form2.Visable=false FROM Form2

What i have tried:

```
Form1 FRM1 = New Form1;
FRM1.Show();
```

What I want: I want to make form1 visible = true from form2 code without creating a new form1

> I can do it with VB.NET but i can't do it with C#

Comment: When you create form2, pass it a reference to form1 and save the reference as a local variable. Then call the Hide() method when you need to.

Comment: still it will make a new form1 instead of the existing form1

Comment: as I'm a beginner can you write me a simple. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass a reference of the form you want to close to the form you want to be able to close it from.

Explicitly passing reference:

```
public class Form1
{
    public Form1()
    {
        new Form2(this).Show();
    }
}

public class Form2
{
    Form1 form1;
    
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        this.form1 = form1;
        form1.Hide();
    }
}
```

Passing the reference by setting Form2's owner:

```
public class Form1
{
    public Form1()
    {
        new Form2().Show(this); // show Form2 with Form1 as it's owner
    }
}

public class Form2
{
    public Form2()
    {
        this.Owner.Hide(); // hide this form's owner, in this case Form1
    }
}
```

Some things you might want to read about:

[the 'this' keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) | [Value vs Reference](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type)

Comment: If you use `form2.Show(this)`, you don't need any reference, just `this.Owner.Hide();` (in `Form2`). Btw, `new Form2(this);` is not exactly correct.

Comment: @Jimi Good to know about passing the owner to `Show()`, learn something new everyday. I think passing the reference is a little easier to follow and understand to a beginner, but I agree the `Show(this)` method would be cleaner. I'll add your suggestion to my answer.